# Bash scripting error

Tags: shell-script, centos

I'm having an error when trying to backup every .qcow2 extension in this directory. How can I do the backup with of everything in the directory a different way?

Here is my script & error:

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( i =1; i<5; i++))
    do
            gzip < /var/lib/libvirt/images/*.qcow2 > /root/bin/backup/full/vm$i.qcow2.backup.gz
    done

./assnBackup.bash: line 5: /var/lib/libvirt/images/*.qcow2: ambiguous redirect
./assnBackup.bash: line 5: /var/lib/libvirt/images/*.qcow2: ambiguous redirect
./assnBackup.bash: line 5: /var/lib/libvirt/images/*.qcow2: ambiguous redirect
./assnBackup.bash: line 5: /var/lib/libvirt/images/*.qcow2: ambiguous redirect
```

foreach script:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0

for f in /var/lib/libvirt/images
    do
            gzip < $f > /root/bin/backup/full/vm$i.qcow2.backup.gz
            i=$((i++))
    done
```

fix:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0

file=/var/lib/libvirt/images/*

for f in $file
do
gzip < $f > /root/bin/backup/full/vm$i.qcow2.backup.gz
    i=$((i + 1))
done
```

Comment: You do know that gzip can only handle one file at a time, right?

Comment: Is there some reason that you are attempting to make an individual gzip of each `.qcow2` file? It would be much easier to have your script move the files into a different directory and then gzip the directory.

Comment: What is that loop supposed to do? You're looping four times, and giving `gzip` the same input on each iteration, just redirected to different files? Do you want to get the same file four times? And if so, why not compress it once, and make copies after? What is it that you're trying to accomplish, in the end?

Comment: Thank you for the responses. What I'm trying to do is back up every .qcow2 file that exists in the /var/lib/libvirt/images directory and send that to a new file.

Comment: Take a look at the foreach script I just added to the post. I think that's something a long the lines of what I should be doing but, there's still an error I need to fix.

Comment: "_still an error I need to fix_". What error?

Comment: gzip: stdin: Is a directory @roaima

Comment: Well, it is. You need your `f` to iterate across the files in that directory.

Comment: Why don't you use `tar` and then `gzip` it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so.

If there are more than one file in the directory, `gzip < /.../*.qcow2` would try to redirect the input of `gzip` from all of them. That's not possible, so Bash gives an error. It would work if the pattern only matched one file.

In the second, you have `for f in /var/lib/libvirt/images`. Well, `for` iterates over the words listed, and here's only one. It doesn't iterate over the contents of a directory by itself: it can be used for other stuff as well, like `for s in foo bar blah ; do echo $s ; done`. So, you need to explicitly tell the shell to expand all the file names there by using a wildcard pattern. `for f in /var/lib/libvirt/images/*.qcow2` would run the loop once for each file with name ending in `.qcow2`, with `f` holding the file name.

---

Now, that should make the `gzip` at least work. Though I still do wonder if you actually want to let go of the original file names when doing the backup copy.

You could do something like this instead:

```
gzip -k "$f" && mv "$f.gz" /root/bin/backup/full/
```

`gzip` by default creates a compressed file with the extension `.gz` tacked on the original file name. Usually, it also removes the original, but `-k` tells it to keep it. Then we move the compressed copy away. So `foo.qcow2` 
would become `foo.qcow2.gz` in the backup directory.

Though if the backup directory is on a different file system (as it should be), the above does involve writing the compressed file twice. Some string manipulation in the shell could work around that:

```
gzip "$f" > "/root/bin/backup/full/${f##*/}.gz"
```

Of course you could also use `tar` to archive the whole directory at once, but with VM images that might be a bit awkward to use, since there's no random access to extracting individual files from a compressed tar archive.